# Vitali covering and find disjoint family balls

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

There is exersice in Folland's book which show that every family $(A_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$in $\sigma$-Algebra,there exists a disjoint famly $(B_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that $U_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}=U_{n=0}^{\infty}B_{n}$.

What is diffrence between the exersice and Vitali covering thereom?

you can find Vitali covering definition in the following link

[Vitali Covering theorem, countable sub-collection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611256/vitali-covering-theorem-countable-sub-collection?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is clear if you look at the two statements. The hypotheses are totally different and the conclusions are totally different.

In the exercise the $A_n$ are elements of some $\sigma$-algebra, and the  $B_n$ are not a subfamily of the $A_n$, although you don't say so,  the $B_n$ are just required to be in the same $\sigma$-algebra.

In the "Vitali" theorem that you link to, which btw is not Vitali at all, it's really Wiener's lemma, a simpler substitute for Vitali, the $A_n$ are *balls*, the $B_n$ are a *subfamily* of the $A_n$, and the conclusion is not $\bigcup B_n=\bigcup A_n$, the conclusion is just $\bigcup A_n\subset \bigcup 3B_n$.

So asking what the difference is makes no sense - it seemms like you haven't read the two statements. They're simply not the same at all.

Why do we need Wiener's lemma if we can find $B_n$ with the same union? When we apply Wiener's lemma we need a *subfamily* of the $A_n$, and we need the $B_n$ to be *balls* - the exercise doesn't give either of those.

Comment: Sorry,I didnt write a family in $\sigma$-Algebra.I know how i solve exercise(Take $B_{1}=A_{1}$and $B_{n}=A_{n}-U_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i}$ )but my problem:if we can find any disjoint family such that its union is equal union orginal set,why we use Vitali covering theorem in some where?